# How to include js file from shared location in sharepoint master page

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, master-pages

I would like to include js file from different location that it's now.
Currently in master page code it looks as below:

```
<SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="ScriptLink1" language="javascript" name="Company/Scripts/myJsfile.js" Localizable="false" runat="server"/>
```

and it works fine.

But what I'd like to do is to change current location of this javascript file. Target location of this .js file is a shared location (" \\v-share\share\javascript ").

Is there any way to include this .js file from shared location in sharepoint master page ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this :

`<script type="text/javascript" src="\\serverip\path\to\jsfile" ></script>`

Comment: oops! it actually worked for me in IE.
FF has got some security feature which might be blocking the shared access

Comment: How did you do this ? As far as i know you can't define source in such  a way: src="\\serverip\path\to\jsfile" on aspx master page.